# How can i make my searchbox icon align with my searchbox input?

Tags: css, flexbox, search-box

i tried "display:flex" and "flex:1" but it doesn't seem to work...is there anything wrong or missing in my css? anybody knows please help me! Thank you so much!
This is my html:

```
div className = "header-search" >
        <
        input type = "text"
        className = "header-searchInput" / >
        <
        SearchIcon className = "header-SearchIcon" / >
        <
        /div>
```

This is my css:

```
.header-search {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 24px;
}

.header-SearchIcon {
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

This is how it looks like with my codes:
[image]

Comment: Align how? What is this supposed to look like? My guess is that the problem is `align-items: center;`

Answer (score 0):

I not only solved your problem but also tried to make it a little better.

```css
.header-search {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 24px;
}

.header-search input{
   outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid orange;
}
.header-search input:focus{
   outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid orange;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
.header-SearchIcon {
height:100%;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-search" >
        <input type = "text"
        class="header-searchInput" / >
       <span class='header-SearchIcon'>search</span>
        </div>
```